# EF Core: Parameterized Query Expects the parameter '@responseMessage' which was not supplied

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following stored procedure that I'm trying to call from my asp.net core MVC web application:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspLogin]
(
    @pUserName VARCHAR(150),
    @pPassword VARCHAR(150),
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)='' OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @userID INT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.[User] WHERE UserName = @pUserName)
    BEGIN
        SET @userID = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.[User] WHERE UserName = @pUserName AND PasswordHash=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword+CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(36))))

        IF(@userID IS NULL)
            SET @responseMessage='Incorrect password'
        ELSE
            SET @responseMessage='Success'
    END
    ELSE
        SET @responseMessage = 'Invalid Login'
END
```

I can call this procedure perfectly fine from within my DB, however I'm trying to call it with this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(User user)
{
    var userName = user.UserName;
    var password = user.Password;
    var message = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "responseMessage",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
        Size = 250,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput,
    };
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.uspLogin @p0, @p1, @responseMessage", userName, password, message);

    return RedirectToAction("Success", "Home", new { email = message.SqlValue });
}
```

When testing out this action, I get the following error:

> SqlException: The parameterized query '(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@responseMessage nvarchar' expects the parameter '@responseMessage', which was not supplied.

What is the right way to get the `output` of this procedure from EF Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change param direction,

```
var message = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "responseMessage",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    Size = 250,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
};
```

And execution line as below and try,

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.uspLogin @p0, @p1, @responseMessage OUT", userName, password, message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check spaces for each parameter which were defined in the stored procs and in your repository methods.

We would need to trim the whitespaces and rerun the program. In our case, We had to remove the whitespaces, once done, the API method was successfully executing....